# How to init an IndexPath with arrayLiteral

Tags: ios, swift

How to create an IndexPath object with the init(arrayLiteral:) initialization method?

I try with:

```
let ip = IndexPath(arrayLiteral: [0,0])
```

but get an error message

> Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type
>   'IndexPath.Element' (aka 'Int')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't expect array but rather a "sequence" of `IndexPath.Element` types.

```
let ip = IndexPath(arrayLiteral: 0, 1) // Array [0,1]
// Excerpt from playground: ""ip 0 row 1"\n"
debugPrint("ip \(ip.section) row \(ip.item)")
```

Comment: It's *not* a sequence btw, it's a variadic parameter.

Comment: @AhmadF: That is why quoted sequence :). Right thank you

Answer (score 8):

The [`IndexPath(arrayLiteral:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral/2908652-init) initializer is part of the [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral) protocol, and its purpose is – as the name says – to initialize an index path from an array literal:

> An array literal is a simple way of expressing a list of values. Simply surround a comma-separated list of values, instances, or literals with square brackets to create an array literal.

Examples:

```
let ip: IndexPath = [0, 0]
let ip = [0, 0] as IndexPath
```

The *compiler* automatically translates this to a call to `IndexPath(arrayLiteral:)`, as you can verify by inspecting the intermediate language with

```
swiftc -emit-sil main.swift

// ...
  %19 = function_ref @$s10Foundation9IndexPathV12arrayLiteralACSid_tcfC : $@convention(method) (@owned Array<Int>, @thin IndexPath.Type) -> @out IndexPath // user: %20
  %20 = apply %19(%3, %8, %4) : $@convention(method) (@owned Array<Int>, @thin IndexPath.Type) -> @out IndexPath
// ...
```

Generally, the `init(xxxLiteral:)` methods are required to make a type conform to a `ExpressibleByXXXLiteral` protocol and used by the compiler, but usually not called directly.

Alternatively use

```
let ip = IndexPath(indexes: [0, 0])
```

Both methods can be used with index paths of arbitrary length.

For a table and collection views one needs index paths with exact length 2, and those can be more expressively created with

```
let ip = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)  // table view
let ip = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0) // collection view
```

but the result is identical.

Comment: Correct for sure. However, I still don't like to use it since it seems to be confusing, the first element is the section value and the second one is the row value. Additionally, if we added more than 2 elements in it, it crashes.

Comment: @AhmadF: `let ip = IndexPath(indexes: [0, 1, 2]); print(ip)` does not crash. Index paths are not restricted to be used with table/collection views.

Comment: Yes, but the issue is when accessing the row (`print(ip.row)`) or the section (` print(ip.section)`), at this point, it crashes. Again, your answer is correct anyway!

Comment: It will create an IndexObject for any given array elements but when accessing a row or section properties, It will crash for cases when a given array elements is different than 2. let g = IndexPath(arrayLiteral: 2); let h = IndexPath(arrayLiteral: 2,3,4)

Comment: @MartinR I would like to see in the answer as well an example with an explicit use of `arrayLiteral` init method

Comment: @Adobels: There is an explicit example in the other answer, therefore I won't repeat it here.

Comment: @Adobels: The `init(arrayLiteral:)` method is used by the *compiler* but not meant to be called directly.